# OrderBy property not working - Xamarin Firebase

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin, firebase-realtime-database

I've seen a few answers here on how to order your Firebase values, but none seem to work on my case.

So, I have the following firebase database:
[image]

display.xaml.cs:

```
private void tabelaRestLoad()
{
    var collection = firebaseClient
        .Child("Example")
        .OrderBy("Date")
        .AsObservable<MyDatabaseRecord>()
        .Subscribe((dbevent) =>
        {
            if (dbevent != null)
            {
                DatabaseItems.Add(dbevent.Object);
            }
        });
}
```

display.xaml:

```
<StackLayout>
    <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding DatabaseItems}" SelectionMode="Single">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />
                            <Label Text="{Binding Date}"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
```

MyDatabaseRecord.cs:

```
public class MyDatabaseRecord
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }    
}
```

As you can see, I'm using OrderBy("Date"), and although thats supposedly the right way, it's not returning the data ordered by Date, it is instead returning as default from firebase, sorted by the order it was entered.

I want to add that I wish to order by desc date.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the library you're using to access Firebase wraps the REST API, which always returns results in an undefined order. From its [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data#section-rest-filtering):

> **Filtered data is returned unordered**: When using the REST API, the filtered results are returned in an undefined order since JSON interpreters don't enforce any ordering. If the order of your data is important you should sort the results in your application after they are returned from Firebase.

So if indeed the library is based on the REST API, `OrderBy()` is only useful for subsequent filtering in the query. To get the results in a specific order, you'll have to (re)order them in your application code.

Comment: My main problem is how can I order them in my code

Comment: You'll have to convert the string you have to an actual date, and then sort on those.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try `OrderByChild("Date")`.

This is because you don't have a `Date` there, you have the object `Item1,Item2` when execute the `OrderBy` method.

2. What I suggest is to sort the result database items in view/or before binding `DatabaseItems.OrderBy(x => x.Date)`.

Another option is - change the query and do sorting of the inner array(Item1,Item2...).
Try:

```
private void tabelaRestLoad()
{
    var collection = firebaseClient
        .Child("Example")
        .AsObservable<MyDatabaseRecord>()
        .AsObservableCollection()
        .OrderBy(x => x.Object.Date)
        .Subscribe((dbevent) =>
        {
            if (dbevent != null)
            {
                DatabaseItems.Add(dbevent.Object);
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But where exactly would I then need to add the code from point 2? I can't quite seem to get it right

Comment: @MMelo31 please see an updated answer, you can apply LINQ to the result of `AsObservableCollection`.

Comment: 1 - 'ChildQuery' does not contain a definition for 'OrderByChild' | 3- 'MyDatabaseRecord' does not contain a definition for 'Object' | Both those return errors to me